# PHP cURL is stretching with Mysql fetch array

Tags: php, sql, api, curl

I'm fairly new to PHP and cURL. I started pulling data from an API with cURL. My goal is to pull id from database for tokenid in URL. I can pull the data as I want, but the website loads too late. It is stretching a lot while pulling data.

It pulls data very fast If I don't use `mysql_fetch_array()`.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM elements ORDER by id");    
while ($result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.joepegs.dev/v2/collections/0x74eb4c2ed6d68e81d4b22d8ed7c74335373e45bb/tokens/$result2[id]",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "x-joepegs-api-key: [...]",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$XmlElement = json_decode($response);
$price = $XmlElement->tokenId;

curl_close($curl);


echo $price;
?>
```

When I didn't use `mysql_fetch_array`, it was pulling the data fast, but I continue to have this problem because I need to pull all the data with id.

Comment: What do you mean by stretching?

Comment: Doing lots of `curl` requests is going to be slow. You should find out if the API has a way to request multiple IDs in a single call.

Comment: I hope that isn't your real API key, you've just exposed it to the whole world.

Comment: I mean, ı get all of the results as I want but it is very laggy. There are 80 id in total but all of them load around 50 seconds.

Comment: Every web API call takes a significant fraction of a second. You need to reduce the number of calls you make.

Comment: In case you're not already aware: `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since PHP 5.5.0 (released June 2013) and completely removed since PHP 7.0.0 (released December 2015). Your use of them indicates you are likely running a version of PHP that is **several years** out of date and probably has critical unpatched security vulnerabilities. You should absolutely not be writing any new code that uses the `mysql_*` extension, and should migrate existing code to MySQLi or PDO as soon as possible. Not doing so represents an unnecessary but potentially severe security risk.

Comment: Is your problem that 50 seconds is too long to make 80 curl requests?  If you are doing 80 requests in 50 seconds or 650 mS per request, that's not bad. So is the problem just the amount of time it takes? What does the `$response` look like? Do you need to get all the fields from your `elements` database?  If, as you say, "mysql_fetch_array" is the problem, I highly doubt it. It appears you are getting a single price for each 80 urls.   What's the problem?  If it is taking too long, where is the bottle neck?